# JSoup not fetch all string from rest api in android?

Tags: android, jsoup

I am trying to get string content from a rest api.But sometimes it dosn't give me whole string and get me only a part of it.What I have to do?

```
  Document docGet = Jsoup.connect("https://api.wallex.ir/v1/depth?symbol=BTTCTMN")
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .timeout(5000)
                    .maxBodySize(0)
                    .get();
```